# Firefox sdk styles-file works only partially

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making firefox addon and I cann't manages styles to show correctly. For example, links color are always what page defines:

main.js:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    contentStyleFile: self.data.url("style.css"),
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.js"), self.data.url("script.js")]
```

style.css:

```
#div_id {background:green}
#div_id a.black {color:black}
```

script.js:

```
$('body').append("<div id='div_id'><a class='black' href='#'>link</a></div>");
```

The result is: `background:green` is working, but `#div_id a.black {color:black}` is not working.

Page define `a` color and addon css-file can't change it. The only way to do it is `$('#div_id a.black').css({'color':'black'})`

What is wrong with addons css files? Why they are working only partially?

Comment: I cannot tell why it doesn't work for you, as you don't provide a reproducible example incl. steps to reproduce, but I recreated a minimal example and it does [work for me](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/209901/latest/) ...

Answer (score 0):

I will use this:

```
var styles = "#div_id {background:green}\
#div_id a.black {color:black}";
$("head").append("<style>"+styles+"</style>");
```

It is ugly, but it works.